# Prove that $d(km) \geq 2d(m)$

Tags: number-theory

> Let the divisor function be denoted by $d(m)$. Prove that if $k > m$, then $d(km) \geq 2d(m)$ where $k,m$ are positive integers.

I was thinking about using the fact that if $a$ divides $m$ then both $a$ and $ka$ divide $km$. How do we use this to prove the statement?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

When $k>m$
$$
n \ |\  m \quad \Rightarrow \quad  kn \ |\  km, \  \  kn \ \nmid \  m
$$